# How to initialize a smart contract using Remix?

Tags: contract-development, remix, contract-deployment, contract-invocation, constructor

I have a contract that has this constructor:

```
constructor(address _nativeTokenWrapper) TokenStore(_nativeTokenWrapper) initializer {}
```

And this `initialize` function:

```
    /// @dev Initiliazes the contract, like a constructor.
    function initialize(
        address _defaultAdmin,
        string memory _name,
        string memory _symbol,
        string memory _contractURI,
        address[] memory _trustedForwarders,
        address _royaltyRecipient,
        uint256 _royaltyBps
    ) external initializer {
        // Initialize inherited contracts, most base-like -> most derived.
        __ReentrancyGuard_init();
        __ERC2771Context_init(_trustedForwarders);
        __ERC721_init(_name, _symbol);

        // Initialize this contract's state.
        _setupDefaultRoyaltyInfo(_royaltyRecipient, _royaltyBps);
        _setupOwner(_defaultAdmin);
        _setupContractURI(_contractURI);

        _setupRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE, _defaultAdmin);
        _setupRole(MINTER_ROLE, _defaultAdmin);
        _setupRole(TRANSFER_ROLE, _defaultAdmin);

        // note: see `_beforeTokenTransfer` for TRANSFER_ROLE behaviour.
        _setupRole(TRANSFER_ROLE, address(0));

        // note: see `onlyRoleWithSwitch` for UNWRAP_ROLE behaviour.
        _setupRole(UNWRAP_ROLE, address(0));

        // note: see `onlyRoleWithSwitch` for UNWRAP_ROLE behaviour.
        _setupRole(ASSET_ROLE, address(0));
    }
```

When I deploy using `Remix` and I try to call the `initialize` function, I get an error saying `"message": "execution reverted: Initializable: contract is already initialized"`.

The problem I am having is that the contract initializes with all of its values empty, there's no owner nor admin or anything.

How can I call the function `initialize` with all the data I need after deploying my smart contract?

Answer (score 1):

your `initialize` function has a modifier `initializer` which i believe you are importing from [here](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/proxy/utils/Initializable.sol).

The modifier requires you to call the `initialize` function while deploying the contract itself, you cant call the function after contract is deployed.

Are you trying to deploy using some upgradable pattern?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to deploy a contract that utilizes an upgradable pattern. The source code is here: https://github.com/thirdweb-dev/contracts/blob/main/contracts/multiwrap/Multiwrap.sol

I understand what you say but how can I call the initialize function then? I am using Remix for deploy. I can even use Truffle if you point me to a migration example for this. Thank you!

Comment: are you using `Transparent Proxy`  pattern?  
  
If yes then you deploy the `logic contract` then a `proxy admin` contract and while deploying the `proxy` you pass the bytes of parameters of the `initialize` function of logic contract as constructor.

Comment: I dont know how to do this process through Truffle. I have done this through brownie.